# Missing MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to a mysql db through php running on my schools unix server.  This is what I am trying:

```
$ php setupDatabase.php 
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /users/cs/summers/Fall2010/webCentric/ass4/sessionTime/setupDatabase.php on line 16
```

Line 16 refers to this line:

```
db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
```

I think this means that the mysql functions where not installed with php.  When I execute `<?php phpinfo(); exit(); ?>` and grep for mysql this is what I get:

```
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' ... '--with-mysql=shared,/usr' '--with-mysqli=shared,/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared,/usr' ...
```

I am not sure if this confirms that mysql is not installed.

**Q**: Am I missing mysql?  Do I need to reinstall php with mysql?

**Q**: I do not have root access to server (obviously).  Will I be able to install this without root access? If yes could someone point me to a tutorial?

**Update**

I just looked in my php.ini file this is what is contained in it regarding the mysql (I have removed comments and mysqli stuff).

```
[MySQL]
mysql.allow_persistent = Off
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mysql.max_links = -1
mysql.default_port =
mysql.default_socket =
mysql.default_host =
mysql.default_user =
mysql.default_password =
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
mysql.trace_mode = Off
```

The file does NOT contain: `extension=mysql.so` is this what is required to enable mysql?  I do not have permissions to modify php.ini can I create another one somewhere or can I use something like an include statement with my code?

Comment: Does your php.ini contain a "extension=php_mysql.so"? (see http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5272345.html for exemple)

Comment: I updated my answer. You should definitely have extension=php_mysql.so on the php.ini. Also, if you're running on a shared hosting, I highly recommend talking to the hosting provider and see if they can fix it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mysql extension disabled on your php.ini.

Edit your php.ini and uncomment (remove the ;)

```
; extension=mysql.so
```

In case you can't edit php.ini, you can override it [this way](http://www.whenpenguinsattack.com/2006/01/20/how-to-override-phpini/).

Comment: Running phpinfo() will tell you where you can find php.ini.

Comment: If you're running a shared server and you can't edit it, you could ask them to do it.

Comment: I agree that the issue is probably related to php.ini

Comment: Can I create a new php.ini in my shared directory?

Comment: Here's how you can override php.ini: http://www.whenpenguinsattack.com/2006/01/20/how-to-override-phpini/

Comment: @ign: I think that that only applies if you are running php with apache.  I just want to run it on the commandline.

Comment: Mh, I see. Then you should probably contact the sysadmin/hosting provider, I guess :S

Comment: Contacted my system admin, he had it fixed in 15 minutes.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

According to your compilation flags, it looks like [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) is installed. I suggest using these functions anyways as they are the *improved* extension.

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini file to see if the mysql extension has been enabled. It looks like it hasn't seeing as you are getting an undefined function error.

Look for this line (in php.ini) and remove the semi-colon, restart your webserver and you should be in touch with mysql.

;extension=php_mysql.dll